# A javascript function, using a loop, if and logic (&&)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, logic

I am using a javascript function with four checkboxes, two of which are the right answer.  I have attempted to use the following code.

```
function q4() {
    var a4 = document.getElementsByName('q4');
        for(i=0; i < a4.length; i++) {
            if(a4[i].checked) {
                if(a4[i].value == "a" && a4[i].value == "d") {
                correctAnswers++;
                alert('This works');
                }
            }// end if first if
        }// end of for loop
}// end of function q4
```

This is to supposed to produce an alert if the values a AND d are correct.

The HTML:

```
<!-- Question 4 -->  
    <div class="question-box">  
        <div class="question"><h3>Question Four: Identify two output devices from the images.</h3></div>
        <div class="answers">  
            <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="a">A)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/printer.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="b">B)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/keyboard.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="c">C)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/scanner.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="d">D)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/speakers.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
        </div>
        <br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Check Answer" onclick="q4()">
    <h3 id="Answer4">&nbsp;</h3>
    </div><!-- end of question four -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line

```
if(a4[i].value == "a" && a4[i].value == "d") {
```

How can `a4[i].value` be `"a"` **and** be `"d"`?

You probably wanted `||` ("or") there, probably combined with checking that `correctAnswers` equals 2 after the loop is done.

---

Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Be sure to declare your variables (such as `i` and `correctAnswers`) in the narrowest scope that makes sense, and in the case of `correctAnswers`, be sure to initialize it (perhaps with `0`).

---

Updated code:

```js
function q4() {
  var a4 = document.getElementsByName('q4');
  var correctAnswers = 0; // declare and initialize `correctAnswers`
  for (var i = 0; i < a4.length; i++) { // declare `i`
    if (a4[i].checked) {
      if (a4[i].value == "a" || a4[i].value == "d") {
        correctAnswers++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (correctAnswers == 2) {
    console.log("Correct!");
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="question-box">
  <div class="question">
    <h3>Question Four: Identify two output devices from the images.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="answers">
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="a">A)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/printer.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="b">B)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/keyboard.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="c">C)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/scanner.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q4" value="d">D)&nbsp;<img src="imgs/speakers.jpg" alt="question image"><br/>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Check Answer" onclick="q4()">
  <h3 id="Answer4">&nbsp;</h3>
</div>
```